# Concatenate data to .net application

Tags: c#, file, append

I want to make a program that concatenates an exe and data into one file.

Basicly:
Program A (Program B, Data) => Program C

Program A will just merge to Streams into one. Even the though of using `copy /b B.exe + file.data` also comes to mind. So I'm not too concerned with how cleanly the files are merged.

The idea is that Program B knows its going to be used in this way and will look for the data. The question that come to mind is how can Program C know where it's exe code ends and the data begins? I know that dos exes used to have header data defining their size but I don't know what exists in .net for this kind of inspection.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I think you might want to revise your question.

Comment: @trickdev - Thanks, I came back from lunch even I could understand what I was asking. It is rewrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could figure out the .exe size from the PE header, there's a simpler way: Write the length of the appended section as the last word along with a magic number. To read it, Seek(-WordSizePlusMagicNumberSize, SeekOrigin.End), read them and verify they are valid.

Comment: This solution came to mind but it would not work in the case of a flat binary concat. How much can I get our of the PE header for this task?

Comment: It's been a very long time since I looked at the structure of a PE file. I would imagine that a google search on "PE File Format" would give you the information you need. The essential format has never changed, and never will. It's overall format changes to accomodate new things like .Net apps, but I don't believe that  would affect how you find your way to the natural end of it. I'm not clear why you can't concat a file and then append the size and a magic number.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to embed data in an executable, could you include the data file as a resource in visual studio instead?

Comment: I was not very clear before. I want to append data to a base exe and have it know where the data begins. Since this will not be done during development in the solution I can't add it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data as an **embedded resource**.

In visual studio add the file you wish to add then change the build action in the file properties from None (the default for non code types) to Embedded Resource. Then compile

The next step rather depends on what you wish to do with it? You can access it from within your app via the ResourceManager or in a similar way you can write another app to pull this resource data from it.

You need some context in your question

OR if you are really talking about two streams the you may be talking about ADS, *Alternate Data Streams*, which, if memory serves, is a pain but there is code out there that gives an easy(ish) API